# Amazon EC2 web server shows an incorrect client IP in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I have one load balancer and three EC2 web servers with Linux and Apache. Whenever I use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP to take website's visitor's IP addresses, It shows me a wrong IP address. When I check the IP in Whois databases then I will find its a reserved IP. I guess its IP of another server in AWS itself instead of client's IP. How Can I get correct client's IP with PHP in EC2 servers?

Comment: It's probably the load balancer's IP... Have you looked at the rest of the `$_SERVER` array whether the load balancer forwards the client's IP in a separate header field?

Comment: Yeah I realized load balancer forwards the IP under       `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`  key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP is a local Amazon IP because the visitors does not connect to your server directly.

Normally the Load balancer forwards the real client IP in the `$_SERVER` array under a new key, in most cases `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`